# how to stop and resume a XNA game for windows phone?

Tags: c#, xna

i have a problem with the stopping of a windows phone xna game.

i thought that i can just use:

```
timer.Stop();
timer.Start();
```

to stop and then start the game again. but this dont work, stop is fine but on start the game dont resume. how to solve this?

the timer is a GameTimer

PS. I'm using a xna/silverlight project not a pure xna game

Comment: Are you talking about Tombstoning?

Comment: no the user should have the option (with a button e.g.) to stop the game and then resume it. i'm not talking about e.g. pressing the screen lock button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just found aout that

```
timer.Stop();
timer.Start();
```

work in a xna/silverlight app.
my problem was a other bug

Answer (score 1):

Take a look into game state management, http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/game_state_management

Comment: the problem is im using a xna/silverlight project :(